# Hanging medium weight things from popcorn ceiling in rental

Tags: ceiling, duct-tape

I'm trying to add hanging lights to a rental property I'm living in. The lights + fixtures are about a pound each.

Unfortunately, the place has this ugly, bumpy popcorn ceiling which makes it very had to stick things to. I tried command strips which failed in minutes. I also tried duct tape which lasted a bit longer but failed after a few hours.

I'm not allowed to modify the ceiling in any non-reversible way (no holes whatsoever).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to attach things to this trash ceiling?

Comment: What type of ceiling is over the popcorn??

Comment: Anything strong enough to hold a pound is just going to pull the paint & popcorn off the ceiling and end up doing more damage than a small hole. You're fighting a losing battle here.

Comment: "I'm not allowed to modify the ceiling in any non-reversible way" ...so why did you get hanging fixtures? You appear to need floor lamps or a different apartment/lease with different rules. Or perhaps floor-standing shelving that you can hang lights from near ceiling level.

Comment: @Ecnerwal They're not really ceiling fixtures. The "fixtures" are just an extension cord with a light attached. I want to hang powerful flood lights pointing downwards above my field of vision to flood my space with light. I tried a couple floor standing lights before trying this, but they took up tons of floor space. The shelving idea is a good one but also takes up floor space.

Comment: @JACK drywall I think?

Comment: There are some picture hangers that come with a thick pin that has a graspable head. Push 4 of these pins around the outside of the fixture, and angle them at 45 degrees away from each other. If the thing falls, use more. When you leave, a dab of spackle will hide your holes.

Comment: Like this -- (not an endorsement): https://www.amazon.com/Plaster-Picture-Hangers-lbs-Solutions/dp/B074VN3NKF

Comment: run a steel cable wall-to-wall near the ceiling

Comment: This is an interesting idea! How do you suggest attaching the steel cables to the wall? The area is about 10 feet across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with popcorn ceiling you won't get a good clean surface for adhesive. I would just screw a hanger in the ceiling and patch it with a tiny amount of drywall compound when done. With the popcorn ceiling your landlord will never notice because of the popcorn texture of the ceiling. You can even get popcorn ceiling texture in a can if you are concerned about it and re-spray over the area when you move out.

Comment: I did this and it is working so far! I'm surprised how thick the sheetrock is above the popcorn ceiling. Drywall hangers have ton's of vertical holding strength!